# Grey line and area in primary editor window in XCode

Tags: xcode

Does anybody know where this line and the grey area to the right of it comes from?

*If it's just a bug, feel free to close this question!*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That line is there to give you an impression on how long your lines should be. It's good practice to keep your code within a certain width, so its readable on different resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

That is the Page Guide.

You can disable it here...

[image]

By unchecking this...

[image]

You can also change the distance that it shows.

It's there to show where your code would wrap on a standard 80 character width terminal.